# How to POST image from Windows Phone 8 to PHP

Tags: image, windows-phone-8

From last few days I am searching on how to upload image from wp8 app to PHP page but I didn't find any best example or tutorial. My requirement is to post image with multiple parameters like user_id or etc.

If you have any sample example or code just share with me I'll be very thankful of you.

Answer (score 1):

Did you have a look at this post on stackoverflow? [POST image to web server in windows phone 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15441803/post-image-to-web-server-in-windows-phone-8)

The HttpClient used in the post can be installed via Nuget which again is a Visual Studio Plugin. If you have to give the PHP some parameters you will have to adjust the URI i.e. add the parameters.